# mapquest app key error 403

Tags: android, mapquest

I am using the mapQuest Android SDK for developing a Navigation app. Whenever I try to create a route with the Route Manager, I get the following error

Status Code: 403[This key is not authorized for this service. If you do not have a key, you can obtain a free key by registering at http://developer.mapquest.com.]

This occurred all of a sudden and since last week I have not been able to form a route

The app key is open and free edition and it starts with F

Creating a new app key does not solve the problem either

Comment: I don't understand why my question has been down voted

Answer (score 0):

It seems the best approach for now is to use your key to hit the Directions API webservice, then parse the result into a line overlay that can be shown on your map, html for a narrative webview, or both.

This thread from the Mapquest developers forum is a good starting point:
http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/forums/-/message_boards/message/1522959